# Regular Expression for specific word

Tags: php, regex

I need to find out the width & height from the below string

```
$embed_code = '<iframe id="streamlike_player" name="streamlike_player" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" src="http://cdn.streamlike.com/hosting/orange-business/embedPlayer.php?med_id=5bad83b03860eab0&width=600&height=391.235955056&lng=fr" frameborder="0" width="600" scrolling="no" height="391"></iframe>';
```

I am using below to find out width & height but its not giving me exact result I want

```
preg_match("/width=\"(.*?)\"/", $embed_code, $w_matches);
preg_match("/height=\"(.*?)\"/", $embed_code, $h_matches);
```

The result is

```
Array
(
    [0] => width="0"
    [1] => 0
)
Array
(
    [0] => height="0"
    [1] => 0
)
```

which should be

```
Array
(
    [0] => width="600"
    [1] => 600
)
Array
(
    [0] => height="391"
    [1] => 391
)
```

Any one have any idea regarding it?
Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Umesh Kulkarni

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @Johnysweb Your comment is inappropriate *and should be deleted.* First off, that damned joke answer does not help anybody, **PERIOD**. Even more importantly, you need to pay attention to what the user is doing. He has variables with little snippets of markup in them. There is abso<CENSORED>lutely nothing whatsoever wrong with using pattern matching on such things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why to use .*, width are always given as digits if you are not defining them in style.
also the regex is matching marginwidth and marginheight first.. you have to do something like this.

```
preg_match("/ width=\"(\d+)\"/", $embed_code, $w_matches);
preg_match("/ height=\"(\d+)\"/", $embed_code, $h_matches);
```

give space before width and height in regex. or use word boundary tag \b instead of space.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that it matches **marginwidth / marginheight** instead of **width / height**. It would be a good idea to add a word boundary before the attributes: `\b`

```
preg_match("/\bwidth=\"(.*?)\"/", $embed_code, $w_matches);
preg_match("/\bheight=\"(.*?)\"/", $embed_code, $h_matches);
```

Answer (score 2):

Its probably because it matches the marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" first.

use:

```
preg_match("/ width=\"(.*?)\"/", $embed_code, $w_matches);
preg_match("/ height=\"(.*?)\"/", $embed_code, $h_matches);
```

Comment: Hi, I think rather to use below

preg_match("/\swidth=\"(.*?)\"/", $embed_code, $w_matches);
preg_match("/\sheight=\"(.*?)\"/", $embed_code, $h_matches);

Answer (score 1):

Your regex finds marginwidth and marginheight cause you included the quotation marks.

Try:

```
preg_match("/width=(\d+)/", $embed_code, $w_matches);
preg_match("/height=(\d+)/", $embed_code, $w_matches);
```

EDIT:

Oha, I missed the explicit width and height attributes at the end of your string (scrolled off). My regexes match these:

ab0&width=**600**&height=**391**.23595

Answer (score 0):

The dead simplest solution is to include the space in front of the word you want to match (ie: match in ' width' rather than 'width').

The flavor of regular expression you use may also support word boundaries, something like `\W` which means "match only a non-word character" or `b` which means "beginning of a word". In this case you want to match "any non-word character followed by 'width", for example `\Wwidth=...` or `\bwidth=...`

Comment: It is an error to call `\b` “beginning of word”. For example, in the pattern `/foo\b/`, that `\b` is definitely not a “beginning of word”. Rather, it’s always a word-boundary transition point. It is precisely equivalent to `(?:(?<=\w)(?!\w)|(?<!\w)(?=\w))`, and for the record `\B` is precisely equivalent to `(?:(?<=\w)(?=\w)|(?<!\w)(?!\w))`.